# list index out of range - how to resolve this?

Tags: python

I got the above error when running this block of code. I have tried using the .append method but the same error came up. Do you have any suggestions to resolve this error?

For some context, Rg can be an N x M matrix but the function only takes the values in the first column for each iteration of i.

```
def Test_Index(Rg):
    n = len(Rg)
    vector = []

    for i in range (1, n+1):
        vector[i] = Rg[i, 1]

    for i in range (1, n+1):
        for j in range (i, n+1):
            if vector[j] < vector [i]:
               tmp = vector[i]
               vector[j] = tmp

    for i in range (1, n):
        if vector[i] < vector[i+1]:
           Test_Index =+ 1

    Test_Index =+ 1

    return Test_Index
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for basic debugging

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This code makes little sense as python code. It looks like an attempt to take R code and translate it to python, without knowing what the relevant differences are.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? Also you can swap two variables by doing something like `x, y = y, x` instead of having to create a temporary variable.

Comment: By the way, this line `Test_Tndex =+ 1` sould be `Test_Tndex += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think indexes of Python lists are 1 based (i.e. first place index is 1), but they are 0 based, meaning a list only has indexes 0 to `len(l) - 1`.

By iterating from 1 to `len(l) + 1` you actually trying to access one element beyond the list - `l[len(l)]`.

And you can not assign to any index of an empty list, you must use `append` if you are going to add a new item to it.

But, what do you mean by "matrix"?
Is `Rg` a list of lists, a NumPy array or some other kind of object?

Assuming it is a list of lists (a "2D" list) you can do what you want with a simple comprehension without bothering with indexes or for loops:

```
vector = [item[0] for item in Rg]
```

Comment: Nice answer, but since they are under the impression that it is 1-based, they probably want  `item[0]` (with maybe a `sorted` somewhere in there as well)

Comment: @JohnColeman you are  right, I missed that one. It does say "first column" in the question which would be at index 0. Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for the copy of Rg first. Or you can append items but remind that indexes starts with 0.

Replace lines:

```
vector = []

for i in range (1, n+1):
    vector[i] = Rg[i, 1]
```

With

```
vector = copy.deepcopy(Rg) #  and add `import copy` at the top of file
```

Comment: But OP is trying to extract a co!umn, not copy the whole thing.

Comment: Looks like he wants to make a sorted copy of given matrix. But it's unclear from this code

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start with zero, so when your range is 1 to len(rg)+1 instead of 0 to len(rg), every single loop will start with your second index instead of your first (Rg[1] instead of Rg[0]) and end one index past the end of your list.

Also vector is an empty list, but you're trying to assign values to it like a dictionary... Any index you reference inside of an empty list, even 0 (though you start with 1), would cause this error.

Maybe try:

```
for item in Rg:
    vector.append(item[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now but line 10 is throwing up another index error "list index out of range".

Comment: I'd need to see the updated line 10 code, but I would assume the issue is similar (referencing either an index for an empty array or using a 1 based index in an array as opposed to 0). Your code had multiple examples of this and I only addressed the first example of each of the 2 different types of issues with indexing I saw in your code instead of fixing the whole thing.